# Has the Sefer Ha-Musar (by Zechariah Dhahiri) been translated into English?

Tags: jewish-books, english

I am looking for an English translation of Sefer Ha-Musar, by Zechariah Dhahiri. Does it exist? If so where could I find it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps consider adding a description or link of this book.

Comment: The author is a Yemenite Jewish. The book was written in 1573, as the Internet said, he describes in 45 chapters his travels, at the age of thirty-seven, throughout India, Iraq, Turkey, Syria, the Land of Israel and Egypt, including a description of Rabbi Yosef Karo (Joseph ben Ephraim Karo)’s seat of learning in Safed.

Comment: i have this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqlN0dGd1JyU0JwSkk and this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8F_PW9P6dqld0M2VmltRTc4QXM  i dont think his book was translated into english though

Comment: @Defilla if you want a user to be notified of your comments put a @ in front of that user's name.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob Is this by any chance R. Zecharya Harofei, R. Yahya ibn Suleiman altabib?

Comment: @mevaqesh no this is yahya bin said https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%A6%27%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zechariah_Dhahiri

Comment: for those uninformed, he is the one accredited to bringing the zohar+qabbala to teimon from the yashivo of yoseif qaro in safad and introducing the safaradi nosah. this caused strife in teimon making the community split into baladi and shaami communties

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, Oh it's ok, thank you very much for sharing. Really.

Comment: @mevaqesh, yeah, i'm new at this awesome site, thank you for the help.